# Linking to a specific object id

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of users, and two views: one table view to list all available users, and one detail view to see the details of a specific user. Now I would like to provide a link in my navigation menu to one special user (the "me" user). I have tried:

```
{{#linkTo "user/me"}}Me{{/linkTo}}
```

Ember says:

```
Assertion failed: The attempt to linkTo route 'user/me' failed. The router did not find 'user/me' in its possible routes: 'users', 'user', 'index'
```

I have also tried with:

```
{{#linkTo "user" "me"}}Me{{/linkTo}}
```

But ember is linking to `#/user/undefined`, and I want `#/user/me`.

How can I link to a specific user id?

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gonvaled/bQ4nu/) jsfiddle to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `UserRoute` that does serialization of the model in that manner.

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize: function(model) {
        return {user_id:model};
    }
});
```

I just used `model` here, you would use some property of the model, typically `id`.

The way to use `linkTo` is to give it the name of resource, independent of nesting, and qualify the dynamic segments.

For instance for, post/1/comment/1. Your `linkTo` would be,

`linkTo 'comment' thePost theComment`

where `thePost` and `theComment` are bindings/variables accessible to the template that correspond to Post-1, and Comment-1.

Here's the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6wKV/).

Edit: You need to load the corresponding model in `setupController`

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    App.User.find(model).then(function(result) {
      controller.set('model', result);  
    });
}
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AH5w6/).

**Update 2** added setupController to the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AxPVh/) (regards intuitivepixel)

Comment: Thanks. The link in the jsfiddle is generated as expected (`#/user/me`), but the view is not displaying data at all.

Comment: Mmmmm. I do not see the setupController in the updated jsfiddle. Something went wrong?

Comment: @gonvaled see the updated answer, I've added the working fiddle

Comment: Thanks @intuitivepixel. Still one issue though: if you take a look at the links in the users table, you see things like: `.../show/#/user/<App.User:ember332:user1953>`, but it should be `.../show/#/user/user1953`. This is something about ember that really annoys me: you tweak one little part of the application, and suddendly the whole thing breaks appart. I mean: I am *only* trying to link to a specific user id, and now I have to do a complete refactoring of the codebase. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have created a manual link, without using `linkTo`, and this is doing what I wanted. This is the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gonvaled/bQ4nu/1/). With this approach there is no need to mess around with the `Routes`, and the original links are not broken.

The code in my navigation bar is now:

```
<nav>
  {{#linkTo "users"}}Users{{/linkTo}}
  {{#linkTo "user" "me"}}Me (bad!){{/linkTo}}
  <a class="ember-view" href="#/user/me">Me (good!)</a>
</nav>
```

This is the generated html:

```
<nav>
  <a id="ember250" class="ember-view" href="#/users">Users</a>
  <a id="ember253" class="ember-view" href="#/user/undefined">Me (bad!)</a>
  <a class="ember-view" href="#/user/me">Me (good!)</a>
</nav>
```

The drawbacks of this approach are:

- I have to manually define the link using `html`, and this seems awkward inside a collection of `linkTo`s. Maybe I should create a `linkToId` handlebars helper for this.
- I have to manually track the route: if something changes in my routes, I need to manually update the `href`. Maybe this could be handled in the `linkToId` helper, by accessing the router configuration.
- The generated link does not have an `ember-id`, and I see no solution for this. No idea what side-effect this can have.